# Angular2: Subscribe valuechanges in formbuilder

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, formbuilder

I'm using ionic2 with angular2 and I have a form built with formbuilder but I want to detect new changes of a certain input.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.purchaseDataForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    kms: ['', Validators.required],
    lts: ['', Validators.required],
    price: ['', Validators.required],
    total: ['', Validators.required]
  });
}
```

So that's how my form is validated but I want to subscribe the valuechanges of the **price** and the **lts** inputs, do you know how to do that?

I'm trying with the following function but it displays `Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of undefined`

```
 ngOnInit() {
  this.purchaseDataForm.price.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
    console.log(value);
  });
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know Ionic but I guess `ionViewDidLoad()` is called after `ngOnInit()`. Just move the code from `ionViewDidLoad()` to the constructor or to `ngOnInit()` before the current code.

You should be able to get the price control using

```
this.purchaseDataForm.get('price').valueChanges.subscribe(va‌​lue => {
```

Comment: Moving the code to the constructor keeps the error but if I move the valuechanges code to the ionViewDidEnter() the error it's a bit different `ionViewDidEnter error: Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of undefined` but my function to detect the valuechanges is ok?

Comment: Uh, I missed the `price`. Try `this.purchaseDataForm.get('price').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {`

Comment: The right instruction is `this.purchaseDataForm.controls['price'].valueChanges.sub‌​scribe(value => {` please update your answer so I can accept it, thanks!

Comment: Did you try `get()`?. AFAIK it's the preferred way. It also allows you to get nested controls with `.get('somegroup.subgroup.price')`

Comment: Yes I tried and I got this `this.purchaseDataForm.controls.get is not a function`

Comment: And without `controls`? I looked it up in the docs and from what I understand it should work without `controls`. Didn't remember exactly.

Comment: You right, it also works without `controls`, thanks!

By the way, I have one more question about the formbuilder and how to disable and input, should I create a new question or you can help through the chat?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40792392/angular2-disable-a-formbuilders-element

Answer (score 6):

The price is not a direct attribute of your form. The price is located in the "controls"-object of your form. So your code should look like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.purchaseDataForm.controls.price.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        console.log(value);
    });
}
```