# Angular2: Disable a formbuilder's element

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-forms

I'm trying to disable an element of my formbuilder after the declaration because I have to validate something once my view is loaded, so this is my formBuilder declaration.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.purchaseDataForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    kms: ['', Validators.required],
    lts: ['', Validators.required],
    price: ['', Validators.required],
    total: ['', Validators.required]
  });
}
```

I have no idea how to do that because I want to disable the `total` element once finished my local validation. I hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.purchaseDataForm.get('price').disable() // .enable()
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/AbstractControl-class.html#!#disable-anchor